# Почему дискор бот не работает

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пробую написать бота в дис, но он не хочет выполнять команды, он даже не активен на сервере. Когда запускаю програму, то ничего не пишеться хотя в других гайдах у них вылазят ошибки и бот становиться активным

[image: введите сюдю описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как решить проблему

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Answer (score 0):

1. Не распространяйте токен бота, обязательно сгенерируйте его заново и никому не показывайте.
2. Попробуйте убрать скобки у декоратора ивента `on_ready` и скорее всего бот заработает.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f"Bot {bot.user.name} has ready")


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx: commands.Context):
   await ctx.send("Hi, im Poggi")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```